# How to call these types of fragments?

Tags: single-word-requests, syntactic-analysis, programming, sentence-patterns

I have three types of sentence fragments:

> Type A: "a sphere with a stem"
>   Type B: "has a worm"
>   Type C: "that is red"

How can I call these fragment types to distinguish them?

---

Context: I want to generate messages from description fragments. For instance, if I got "`the apple`", the messages would be

> 1a: "the apple *is* a sphere with a stem"
>   1b: "the apple has a worm"
>   1c: "the apple that is red",

or, for "`here is`", I would want to write

> 2a: "here is a sphere with a stem"
>   2b: "here is *something that* has a worm"
>   2c: "here is *something* that is red"

As you can see, depending on the type of the fragment, I may have to insert some "glue" words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type A is a [noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase), Type B is a [verb phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase), and Type C is ambiguous by itself, but in the context of your examples it's a [restrictive or defining clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-restrictive_clause).

Comment: At the very least, (C) is a clause. BTW, if you're doing any programming on this, there are a few things you might want to consult.